# Show that $H$ is a subspace of $M(2\times 2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M(m\times n)$ be the set of $m \times n$ matrices. This is easily shown to be a vector space using the usual rules of addition of matrices and multiplication by a scalar. Let $F$ be a fixed $2 × 2$ matrix.

Show (using the definition of subspace) that the set $H$ of matrices $A$ in $M(2\times 2)$ that commute with $F$ (meaning $AF = FA$) is a subspace of $M(2\times 2)$.

If $F= \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$ write the space $H$ corresponding to $F$ as a span of two matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The readers may be more eager to help if you could explain how did you approach the problem and where you get stuck.

Comment: I have been able to prove a set as a subspace before but the addition of matrices A and F (that commute, AF = FA) is throwing me off. And the second half is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @user96760 It is best to add such explanations to your question.

Answer (score 2):

To check that $H$ is a subspace, you need to check that:

1. $0 \in H$. This is trivial.
2. If $A,B \in H$, then $A+B \in H$. Go by the definition: if $AF=FA$ and $BF = FB$, is it true that $(A+B)F = F(A+B)$?
3. If $c \in \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is your field (probably $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$), does $AF = FA$ imply that $(cA)F = F(cA)$?

As for the span, let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in H.$$

Then $AF = FA$, i.e.,

$$\begin{bmatrix} a+3b & 2a+4b \\ c+3d & 2c + 4d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a+2c & b+2d \\ 3a+4c & 3b+4d \end{bmatrix}.$$

Solve the system, i.e., find $a,b,c,d$, and you're done!

However, you could also use a trick. You're told that the span has 2 (linearly independent) matrices. So, notice that $F$ commutes with $F$ and $I$ (the identity matrix), and that these two are linearly independent.